# How to get Microsoft Graph APIs group related permissions with administrator's consent

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We are working on an App to integrate with Microsoft graph API. Now I can sign in with Microsoft Graph API with user's grant accesses such as to read user's profile etc, for both a work account and personal account.
We want to read user's group information if it's a Microsoft work account. From the [doc](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes), to read user's group info, we need the administrator's consent. But how do we get that? I searched around but failed to get the answer. Do we need to contact each tenant's administrator to get them authorize our app?

From this [link](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/release_notes) group section, it seems we can't get the group permission when user signing in clicking accept button. May I ask how long it takes if you want to support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fei's answer is technically correct. I suspect however that the confusion here has more to do with the meaning of "administrator's consent" than how to request those scopes.

When we talk about "administrator's consent" we are really saying that those scopes can only be used when the user login in as administrative privileges. It does *not* mean that an Administrator needs to give consent to a User before they can be enabled.

- User Scopes can be used for any account
- Administrative Scopes can only be used with administrator accounts

Comment: There's actually a third element here, which is the ability for the administrator to consent on behalf of the organization (irrespective of whether the request permissions can be consented by a user or must be consent by an admin).  Consent on behalf of the org will allow any user in the org to use the application with consent being suppressed.  Not sure if this is available yet on V2.  On the v1 endpoint you can enable admin consent on behalf of the org by passing prompt=admin_consent in the querystring on the authorize request.

Comment: Oh and additionally we're working on some new user consentable group permissions, which we hope to make available soon (no ETA though)

Comment: That does work well with the v1 endpoint. Unfortunately "admin_consent" isn't a valid prompt option with v2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll forward this to my teammates on this.

Answer (score 2):

With the V2.0 endpoint, we can specify the permissions your app needs dynamically, at runtime, during regular usage of your app. To do so, we can specify the scopes your app needs at any given point in time by including them in the scope parameter of an authorization request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https:%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fgroup.read.all+openid+offline_access&client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirectURL}
```

And to give the consent for the scope which need admin, we need to ensure that the login-in account has the administrator privilege. More about the v2.0 endpoint you can refer to [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/).

Answer (score 0):

Before your application can use admin-restricted scopes, you need the administrator to consent. Once an administrator of a tenant has consented, you will be able to successfully request those scopes for users in that tenant.  For more information, see this topic on admin-restricted scopes and how to send a request for admin consent:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#admin-restricted-scopes.  Yes, you'll need the admin of each tenant using your app to do this.