# How to use MS Graph to access files stored in a group without administrator privileges

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

My app needs to access the files stored in a group's default document library as described in the [docs](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive) like this:

```
/groups/{group-id}/drive
```

In order to do this the app needs to obtain the group ID. But according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802404/how-to-get-microsoft-graph-apis-group-related-permissions-with-administrators-c/37806655) and the documentation the authenticated user needs administrator privileges if the app wants to read the users's group information.

How can the app obtain a group ID if the authenticated user does not have admin privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app need to be consented once by the administrator and after that it can access the information it requires. The permission scope required to access groups (Groups.Read or Groups.ReadWrite) require an administrator to consent, and the administrator can consent on behalf of the entire organization, in this case when a regular user uses the app they will not see a consent UI and the app will be able to access the information on their behalf. Code sample here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2